# Bar plot with confidence intervals looks different with yerr parameter

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart, confidence-interval

Firstly,  sorry if someone already asked this question about this plot (I have trailed through several stackoverflow posts already).

[image: thedesiredplot]

The plot has the four mean value bar charts with the margin of error (margin=mean +-std*1.96) represented by the vertical lines on top of them.

Anyway, the issue that I'm having is that my bar plot looks fine without the yerr parameter.

[image: myplotofmeans]

However, as soon as I introduce the yerr parameter, yerr=df.std(axis=1), into plt.bar, the mean value bars become centered around 0 and small. see the picture.

[image: myplotwithyerr]

I honestly dont know where the issue is.
I have tried experimenting with confidence intervals as well,and I'm still getting the same plot, when the yerr parameter is introduced.

```
upper=[1.96*s[i] for i in range(4)], lower=[(-1.96)*s[i] for i in range(4)],
ci=list(zip(lower,upper))
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
xt = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
plt.xticks(xt)
bar_plot = plt.bar(df.index, df.mean(axis=1),capsize=10)
#bar_plot = plt.bar(df.index, df.mean(axis=1),,yerr=df.std(axis=1)*1.96, capsize=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use seaborn's barplot:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(data=df.stack().reset_index(name='value'),
            x='level_0',
            y='value',
            color='C0')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your yerr to

```
df_std = df.std(axis=1)/np.sqrt(df.shape[1])
yerr = df_std*1.96
```

It should work